# Struts 2 : link + img does double request, but why?

Tags: html, jsp, hyperlink, struts2, request

i have a big problem. I have a list with some values. And every Time I click on it, it toggles the sorting from ASC to DESC OR from DESC to ASC. Now I want to show a img that shows the status of the sorting (arrow up for ASC, and arrow down for DESC). 
Without the img it works great, but when i put the dynamic img Tag into it, i sends a double request to the Server, so that the toggeling cant function .
My logic is like this: if DESC was before than now use ASC.... if Asc was before than now use DESC.
My JSP looks like this (getSort() returns the actual String of the sort "status"):

```
    `<s:if test="getSort()=='DESC'">
    <s:set name="sortierBild1" value="'/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF'"/>
    </s:if>
    <s:if test="getSort()=='ASC'">
    <s:set name="sortierBild1" value="'/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF'"/>
    </s:if>`




   `<th id="Berichtsjahr" class="sortable">
    <s:url id="SortBerichtsjahrURL" action="planIdentUebersicht_sort">
    <s:param name="sortBy" value="1" />
    </s:url>
    <a href="${SortBerichtsjahrURL}" class="action">BJahr
    <img src="<s:url value='%{sortierBild1}'/>" class="icon"></a>
    </th>`
```

With this constelation it sends double requests, and my logic cant toggle!
The same code without the img-part (`<img src="<s:url value='%{sortierBild1}'/>" class="icon">`), functions great!

Please help me!
Greetings.

Comment: My browser is Firefox and there it does not work. In IE6 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter `<s:set name="sortierBild1" value="'/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF'"/>` sets the value `sortierBild1` to `'/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF'`. Your `<img src="<s:url value='%{sortierBild1}'/>"` will look this way when the value is put in there:

```
<img src="<s:url value=''/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF''/>"
```

I guess the 2x single quotes will break the tag or generate a tag like this:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.tld/app/'/styles/img/buttons/pfeil-unten.GIF'" />
```